# What can I eat the night before to help me get up in the morning?

Tags: nutrition, energy

What can I eat the night before I go to bed to help me get up in the morning?

My issue is not waking up, or being lazy, nor is it my body being sore. But there are times when my body will refuse to move in the morning and it will sometimes take me anywhere from 15 to 45 minutes before I can gather enough energy to push myself into a sitting position.  Once sitting I'm a bit better and once I get something into my stomach everything is fine.

From everything I'm reading, pretty much anything I eat before I go to bed will get used by as energy, to rebuild muscle or get stored as fat.  Currently, I'm taking a casein shake before going to bed which hasn't had any negative effect.

Anyone have a clue.  Should I just have a jar or raisins on the night stand as quick energy in the morning?

Update: Well, I do not know if this is fitness related or not, that's the issue. I do go to the gym three times a week and workout fairly intensely. I have also started counting calories in the last couple of weeks to stay within 1800 calories daily and adding more based on whatever activity I'm doing.  And have been slowly burning off fat, hopefully.

My caloric intake is 50/50 carbohydrate/protein (hovering at 200 grams each), fat will vary from 10 to 40 grams day to day.  But as I said I'm keeping caloric intake to around 1800 calories, so on days when I consume more fats, I'll usually intake less carbohydrates and protein.

At the gym I usually burn about 600 calories on weights alone and the scale seems to confirm that.

Hope that's enough information.

Comment: The question begs for more detail which Robert touches upon in his [answer](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/6215/241). However, nutrition questions unrelated to exercise are considered off-topic for the scope of this site. Consider rewriting it, and if it fits within the scope defined in the [faq] then it can easily be reopened.

Comment: 1800 calories strikes me as extremely low for an active person.

Comment: I'm doing 1800 calories and if I do 45 minutes of high intensity weights I'll consume an additional 200-300 calories.

Answer (score 1):

Could you explain what you mean a little bit more? You say that it isn't being lazy and that leads me to believe it isn't just a casual "I'm tired and don't **want** to get out of bed" sort of feeling. If you are seriously facing a situation where despite your best effort you are suffering from some sort of near paralysis you might need to see a doctor. If it is just a casual feeling of lethargy try placing your alarm on the other side of the room and cranking it up loud.

A strategy I have used is taking melatonin at night. When I take it and have a good night's sleep I wake up feeling very rested and just plain content. It's quite easy to get out of bed when I feel that way.

Comment: It's not paralysis, it's just that I don't have the strength to push my own weight.  I'll try talking to my GNC girl.